# How to make 2D array of JCheckBoxes?

Tags: java, arrays

I have to make a 2D array of `JCheckBoxes` in Java. I'm using the code below, but when I try to set selected true:

```
checks[0][1].setSelected(true);
```

it says that `checks[0][1]` is `null`.

```
JCheckBox[][] checks = new JCheckBox[14][14];

for (int i = 0; i < 14; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 14; j++) 
        this.add(new JCheckBox(""));
```

Comment: So where have you assigned `checks[0][1]`?

Comment: im new in java but i think when im making the array it assig checks[0][1]

Comment: No, it doesn't.  It sets it to `null` unless and until you assign something else to it.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create each `JCheckBox` in the array and then add it. I'd also suggest using named constants instead of magic numbers, like so:

```
final int NUM_BOXES = 14; // named constant
JCheckBox[][] checks = new JCheckBox[NUM_BOXES][NUM_BOXES];

for (int i = 0; i < NUM_BOXES; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < NUM_BOXES; j++) 
        checks[i][j] = new JCheckBox("");
        this.add(checks[i][j]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer bro, but idk why this line gave me an erro this.add(checks[i][j]);r  in the variable J

Comment: It seems like you're using a capital `J` instead of a lowercase `j`.

Comment: That or your second for loop doesn't have opening and closing brackets (`{ ... }`), without those the for loop only executes the line directly below it.

Comment: another question bro, im trying to mark one checkbox can i use this codechecks [0] [1].setSelected(true); or what?